# GLM with nested predictor and non-nested outcome

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, nested-data

I am using GLM to analyze the effect of career type (4-category discrete) on performance score in a competition (1-100 continuous). I am interested to know whether a particular career type results in a higher performance score, as well as whether there is a difference in performance scores between career types.

For the next competition, participants have been allowed enter as teams of 2 or more individuals. Each team is only assigned one performance score, but there can now be multiple career types associated with each score. Ideally, I would like to use the data collected from the next competition to make inferences consistent with those from previous years, but it does not seem possible without aggregating the career type variable for each team (e.g., binning each entry based on the team's career type composition).

How can I properly model the effect of career type on performance score in this situation?

Comment: Is it not an option to have 3 dummies for career type (as you presumably had in your previous model) and then set up to two of them per team? This assumes that the career type is linearly additive regardless of who they are teamed up with, but sticks to the same model structure as before.

Comment: Yes, but this does not account for the dependence of the effect of career type on team membership. Perhaps I just need to model the interaction between career type and team ID.

Comment: You'll want the interaction between career types for that, but those could not have been modelled in your previous situation so that would reduce consistency (though possibly improve generalizability).